# decimal to double

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, double, decimal

I have something like this.....

```
foreach (var pupilAvg in pupilsAvgs) {
    Report_TeachersPosition teacher = new Report_TeachersPosition();
    teacher.ORG_ID = pupilAvg.ORG_ID;
    teacher.Yearcode = pupilAvg.YearCode;
    teacher.Teacher_K5 = pupilAvg.PupilsAvg_K5 / ratio.ClassKto5;
    teacher.Teacher_6to8 = pupilAvg.PupilsAvg_6to8 / ratio.Class6to8;
    teacher.Teacher_9to12 = pupilAvg.PupilsAvg_9to12 / ratio.Class9to12;
    teacher.Teacher_EPSFTE = teacher.Teacher_K5 + teacher.Teacher_6to8 
                             + teacher.Teacher_9to12;
    teacher.Teacher_Adjusted_EPSSalary = teacher.Teacher_SAUEPSMatrix
                                         * teacher.Teacher_Ratio;
    teacher.Teacher_ElementarySalary = teacher.Teacher_Adjusted_EPSSalary 
                                       * entities.Report_Attending_Pupils_Avg.ToList()
                                       .Where(x => x.ORG_ID == pupilAvg.ORG_ID 
                                       && x.YearCode.Equals("" + yearCode))
                                       .FirstOrDefault().PupilsAvg_K8_Percentage;
    teacher.Teacher_SecondarySalary = teacher.Teacher_Adjusted_EPSSalary 
                                      * entities.Report_Attending_Pupils_Avg.ToList()
                                      .Where(x => x.ORG_ID == pupilAvg.ORG_ID 
                                      && x.YearCode.Equals("" + yearCode))
                                      .FirstOrDefault().PupilsAvg_9to12_Percentage;
}
```

but the `class` is...

```
public partial class Report_TeachersPosition {
        public int ORG_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Yearcode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_K5 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_6to8 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_K8 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_9to12 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_EPSFTE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_ActualFTE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_Ratio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_TotalSalary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_ElementarySalary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_SecondarySalary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_SAUEPSMatrix { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Teacher_Adjusted_EPSSalary { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is... In the `class Report_TeachersPosition`, I have all `decimal` values from `database`. And I want them to be in `double`. So i change it into `double` and save it. but when I open it again, Its back to `decimal`.. I dont know why.. Can somebody help????

Answer (score 1):

If your database is storing the values as `decimal` then everytime you fetch them from the database they are always going to come back as `decimal`.

The more important question is *why* do you want the values as `double`? If it's for display purposes then I would recommend you use appropriate formatting. Bare in mind, you will lose accuracy when you convert from `decimal` to `double`.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot use"?

Comment: @TuHazlo "*cannot use decimal in visual studio*" eh?

Comment: @TuHazlo, please explain why you cannot use decimals. Decimal is probably the most appropriate representation for your data - that's why the generated class contains `decimal` values.

Answer (score 0):

Is public partial class Report_TeachersPosition a database generated class? (I suppose yes). You must change type of database table column and then regenerate model class